# Calculating the uncertainty in the accuracy of a model

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How do I calculate the uncertainty in the accuracy of a model, when the model has only predicted for very few samples? For eg. I have a model which has correctly predicted X times out of N times. So the accuracy is X/N. However, if N is small (lets say < 10) then there is pretty good chance that X/N is not the actual accuracy (there is some uncertainty)

Is there a mathematical way for me to quantify the uncertainty of the precision?

For example, if N is only 10 and X is 6, the accuracy is 0.6 +/- some large uncertainty. But when N is 10000 and X is 6000, the accuracy is also 0.6, but the uncertainty in this case would be very low (or even negligible).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably interested in [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). There are a lot of online calculators for it, the first I found that accepts number of successes as parameters (doesn't require you to calculate standard deviation by hand, which is not hard, but why do it when it's not necessary?) is https://sample-size.net/confidence-interval-proportion/

For 6 successes out of 10 the 95% confidence interval is $[0.2624, 0.8784]$, for 6000 out of 10000 it's $[0.5903, 0.6096]$.

Note that 95% interval doesn't mean that your true accuracy is in this range with 95% probability (you can't even speak about such probability unless you have some prior expectations about accuracy, and then you need to calculate the posterior probability differently than confidence interval), but rather it's calculated in such way that for *any* given accuracy, if you repeat your experiment many times (ie take many selections of 10 samples each), then true accuracy will be in the confidence interval 95% of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I do see some other places use a different formula/algorithm than the link you sent. For eg. https://openstax.org/books/introductory-business-statistics/pages/8-3-a-confidence-interval-for-a-population-proportion - would you know which one is correct?

Comment: There are different formulas in the links I sent. They differ mostly by which approximation of binomial distribution to use (or work with it exactly, but it becomes harder as sample size grows), and for any reasonable sample size all approximations give almost equal values.